# Adding a note to certain elements in an array if they meet requirements

Tags: java, arraylist

So what my program is supposed to do...

1. Iterate through an array of 113 numbers
2. Print said numbers

But if..

- number is odd print "odd" beside it
- number is divisible by 5 print "hi five"
- total number of x and its subsequent number (x+1) is divisible by 7 print "wow"
- number is prime print "prime"

Currently my program will iterate through the numbers and print the ones that apply, and if two apply it will print it twice with different notes. What i would like to do is have it print all the numbers, then print the notes beside the numbers that apply. And if two conditions apply, print the notes beside each other and not on new lines.

ex. of what i would like it to do..

x: 5, odd, high five

Ive been trying different techniques from some examples i found but to no avail. Any direction or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

P.S. - i know i haven't implemented prime yet, my equation isn't right, thats next on my list.

Here is what i have so far..

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Number {

public static ArrayList<Integer> getSequence() {
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(113);

    for (int n = 0; n <= 113; n++) {
        numbers.add(n);
    }
    return numbers;
}


public static boolean isOdd(int n) {
    if (getSequence().get(n) % 2 != 0) {
        System.out.println("x: " + n + ", x is odd");
    }
    return true;
}


public static boolean isDivisibleBy5(int n) {
    if (getSequence().get(n) % 5 == 0) {
        System.out.println("x: " + n + ", hi five");
    }
    return true;
}


public static boolean isDivisibleBy7(int n) {
    int x = getSequence().get(n) + (getSequence().get(n) + 1);

    if (x % 7 == 0 && x<113) {
        System.out.println("x: " + n + ", wow");
    }
    return true;
}


public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return false;
    }
        for (int i = 2; i < Math.sqrt(n); i++) {
            System.out.println("x: " + n + ", prime");

            if (n % 1 == 0) {
                return false;
            }
    }
    return true;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> nums = getSequence();

    for (int n : nums) {
        if(isOdd(n)) {
        }
        if(isDivisibleBy5(n)){
        }
        if(isDivisibleBy7(n)){
        } 

    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is an extended version of a common test to see if you are a good programmer. Apparently you failed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Integer arraylist create a separate class which can hold `Integer` and `ArrayList<String>`. Then  create your arraylist of that class type.

Make methods in your new class as follows

- Method to insert the number
- Method to retrieve the number
- Method to insert a label to the array list.
- Method to retrieve the `ArrayList` or `String[]`
  This way you can easily overcome your problem.

One other method is to use a Map object(`HashMap` instead). `Integer` as the KEY and `ArrayList<String>` as the VALUE.